# How to validate string in SQL with characters

Tags: sql, string, t-sql

Check if the string is following the correct format or not. The correct format is as follows: 
0000/00000. So far this is what i have got:

```
declare @ID nvarchar = '0000/00000'


SELECT (case when len(@id) not between 1 and 12 OR @id not like( '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' + '/' + '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
                                 OR LEFT(@id,13) LIKE '%[0-9]&' then 'OK' else 'ERROR' end
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `not like`?

```
where @id not like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

I assume that "0" means that any digit is allowed.

Comment: Nope - the only acceptable ID is 0000/00000. It keeps things simple  ;)

Comment: So you are looking for `WHERE @id = '0000/00000'`?!

Answer (score 0):

First, this will be a problem:

```
declare @ID nvarchar = '0000/00000'
```

**This:**

```
declare @ID nvarchar = '0000/00000';
SELECT @ID LEN(@ID), DATALENGTH(@ID);
```

**Returns:**

```
ID   LEN
---- ----
0    1
```

With that in mind, note that this: `PATINDEX({your pattern},@Id)` will return a natural Boolean result.

```
DECLARE @ID1     NVARCHAR(1000) = '5555/12312',
        @ID2     NVARCHAR(1000) = '1234/12345678',
        @pattern VARCHAR(100)   = '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';

SELECT IsCool = PATINDEX(@pattern,f.Id)
FROM   (VALUES(@ID1),(@ID2)) AS f(Id);
```

**Returns:**

```
IsCool
-----------
1
0
```

If, by `0000/00000` you mean: Four digits + "/" + five digits then these expressions all work (note I made the pattern a variable for cleaner, easier to read code, it's not required):

```
DECLARE @ID      NVARCHAR(1000) = '5555/12312',
        @pattern VARCHAR(100)   = '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';

SELECT CASE PATINDEX(@Pattern,@ID) WHEN 1 THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'Error' END;
SELECT  IIF(PATINDEX(@Pattern,@ID)>0,'Ok','Error');
SELECT  CHOOSE(PATINDEX(@Pattern,@ID)+1,'Error','Ok');
```

Your code suggests that @ID can be up to 12 characters long. Let's say, for example, the acceptable formats were:
0000/00000
0000/000000
0000/0000000

Then you could do this:

```
DECLARE @ID      NVARCHAR(1000) = '5555/12312';

SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(@ID)<13 AND SIGN(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]',@ID)) * 
                 PATINDEX('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@ID) = 1
            THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'Error' END;
```

**Two final thoughts:**

1. `LEN({string})` can't be negative;  LEN(@ID) < 13 will do the trick
2. If the max length is really 12 then make the parameter or variable NVARCHAR(13). This way, for example, someone passes in an 8000 character string, SQL doesn't have to scan the whole thing to determine that it's not valid.